# error looping through Ajax (JSON) response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to loop through an array that gets returned from a php file.

If I run this:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib/search/search.standards_one.php",
        async: "false",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {subjects: subjects, grades: grades},
        success: function(response){
            $("#standards_results").html("");
            $.each(response[0], function(){
                  console.log(this['code'], this['standard_id']);
            });
            }
        });
```

everything works perfectly.

but, I need to loop through this response using an array (grades) as parameters.

like this:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib/search/search.standards_one.php",
        async: "false",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {subjects: subjects, grades: grades},
        success: function(response){
                $("#standards_results").html("");
                var len = grades.length;
                var param = "";
                for(var x=0; x < len; x++){
                    param = grades[x];
                    $.each(response[param], function(){
                    console.log(this['code'], this['standard_id']);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

however, when I run this I get the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error.

I've tried a number of different solutions, but I still arrive at this result.

////

this is where the JSON object gets created:

```
  private function retrieve_standards_one(){
    $dbh = $this->connect();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT code, standard_one_id 
                           FROM standard_one 
                           WHERE grade_id = :grade_id 
                           ORDER BY standard_one_id");
    $stnd = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < (count($this->grades)); $x++){                    
    $stmt->bindParam(':grade_id', $this->grades[$x], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stnd[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    $json = json_encode($stnd);
    return $json;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the JSON?

Comment: grades is undefined on your success block. you must define it by using the response you get.

Comment: What does the function return -- is the grades object there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grades` is out of scope of your success function, that is why it is undefined. The ajax is asynchronous, so the call is fired off, and your `success` function is only executed when the response is received (and it was successful).

A quick fix would be to put the vars you need in the global scope, or get them from `response` if they are in there.

```
var len = response.length;
```